# Is it possible to open a browser in private mode in iOS using .net maui?

Tags: ios, url, browser, maui, private

We are developing a mobile application using .net maui.

Within this application we need to open an external url to an authenticated web site.

We need to guarantee that the user needs to authenticate each time the user opens the external url

The behavior we are looking for is somehow similar to open a browser in private/incognito mode.

How can we achieve for the iOS version?

I did not find any instruction on how to do that.

Comment: Assuming that you are using `WKWebView`, you need to figure out how to set the appropriate [configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1395661-websitedatastore)

Comment: No, in .net maui, i'm using: await Browser.Default.OpenAsync(_viewModel.OMNIANotificationParamter.NotificationURL, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);

Comment: You need to work out what Maui is doing "under the covers" when you do that. If it stays within your app then it is probably using WKWebView or SFSafariViewController. For the latter I don't believe there is any way to force "private" mode